# MultiBinding, если один из Binding.Patch не существует

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть `MultiBinding`

```
  MultiBinding mb = new MultiBinding() { TargetNullValue = ""};

  mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Model.DisplayString") { Source = this, TargetNullValue="" });
  mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Model.ParentObject.DisplayString") { Source = this, TargetNullValue = "" });
  mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Model.ParentObject.ParentObject.DisplayString") { Source = this, TargetNullValue = "" });
  mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Model.ParentObject.ParentObject.ParentObject.DisplayString") { Source = this, TargetNullValue = "" });
  mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Model.ParentObject.ParentObject.ParentObject.ParentObject.DisplayString") { Source = this, TargetNullValue = "" });
  mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Model.ParentObject.ParentObject.ParentObject.ParentObject.ParentObject.DisplayString") { Source = this, TargetNullValue = "" });
  ...
  mb.StringFormat = "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}";
  this.SetBinding(TitleProperty, mb);
```

однако, например, `Model.ParentObject.ParentObject` может быть `null`, при этом строка в `mb` перестаёт формироваться. Что делать в этой ситуации?

Comment: А если FallbackValue для биндингов указать?

Comment: @Alexey да! всё сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Привязка успешно возвращает значение, если:
>
> ```
> Путь к источнику привязки разрешен.
>
> Преобразователь значений, если таковые имеются, способен преобразовать полученное значение.
>
> Полученное значение является допустимым для привязки свойства target (цель).
> ```
>
> (с)MSDN

Видимо в данном случае одно из этих условий не выполняется, что приводит к Fail'у, вероятно сам Binding (а не его значение) становится Null и при попытке им оперировать срабатывает NullReferenceException перехватываемое где-то в недрах методов биндинга и выкидывающее наружу null либо пустую строку.

Установка `BindingBase.FallbackValue` позволяет решить данную проблему